# Mysql how to use ifnull based on priority level?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

This is the example of my query result
(i have access to these values in SELECT)

```
   rate_default        rate_weekend     seasonal_rate    
   250.0               280.0            300.0
   250.0               null             300.0
   250.0               280.0            null
   250.0               null             null
```

Based on my result i would like to get only one output instead of the result that i produce above.
Based on these three columns, the rate conditions are:

Priority:

seasonal_rate > rate_weekend > rate_default

so if seasonal is not null select seasonal.
How do i select the final output in mysql?

Comment: You want four result rows, but with one column only? Values 300, 300, 280, 250?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USE COALESCE()

`COALESCE(seasonal_rate, rate_weekend, rate_default);`